# Routing: Choose template dependent from URL

Tags: bolt-cms

I want to provide a printer friendly/text only version for a specific content type. So I need to render the same content type with different templates dependent from URL

Example: article/slug should use article.twig, while article/slug/print should use print.twig

Is this possible? Or do I have to write an extension?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a little hack, but it works. I'm using these lines in the routing.yml:

```
printcontentlink:
  path:               /{contenttypeslug}/{slug}/print
  defaults:           { _controller: 'Bolt\Controllers\Frontend::template',template:'print' }
  requirements:
    contenttypeslug:  'Bolt\Controllers\Routing::getAnyContentTypeRequirement'
```

And added this at the top of print.twig:

```
{% set currentslug = paths.current|replace({'/print':''}) %}

{% setcontent record = currentslug  %}
```

The better solution would be to write a new controller or extend the record controller which has a "template" argument.